# Forge viewer rooms color changes were not working

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have a list of levels, on click of each level it is showing the rooms. I want to change the color of each room object. I have tried with the following code snippet:

```
var selSet1 = NOP_VIEWER.getSelection();
NOP_VIEWER.clearSelection();
var color = new THREE.Color( 255 / 255, 0, 0, 1 );
for( let i = 0; i < selSet1.length; i++ ) {
    NOP_VIEWER.setThemingColor( selSet1[i], color );
}


Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.prototype.setColorMaterial = function(objectIds, color){
  if( !(color instanceof THREE.Color) ) throw 'Invalid argument: Color';
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial
      ({
        color:      color,
        opacity:    0.8,
        transparent: true
      });
    NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman().addMaterial( 'ColorMaterial-' + new Date().getTime(), material, true );
};
```

Both were not working, can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument of the function `viewer.setThemingColor` only accepts `THREE.Vector4`, that's why it doesn't work for you. You have to change your code into this way, and please check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874364/7745569):

```
var selSet1 = NOP_VIEWER.getSelection();
NOP_VIEWER.clearSelection();
var color = new THREE.Vector4( 255 / 255, 0, 0, 1 );
for( let i = 0; i < selSet1.length; i++ ) {
    NOP_VIEWER.setThemingColor( selSet1[i], color );
}
```

Here is the Viewer documentation: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/

hope it helps.