# View Model's Objects

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We have a solution that upload and view models using model-derivative APIs. We were able to upload and view models successfully, but we want to view specific objects on the model (last group of children in the tree).

We need to know how to view these objects and if there is a way, we can get all the children dbIds from the parent dbId. We are using viewer version 7.

Answer (score 0):

The way of getting leaf nodes hasn't been changed in v7.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874364/7745569

```js
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
let leafNodeDbIds = await getLeafNodes( model, [123] )
```